# Using Perl to parse text from blocks

Tags: perl

I have a file with multiple blocks of test. FOR EACH block of test, I want to be able to extract what is in the square bracket, the line containing the FIRST instance of the word "area", and what is on the right of the square bracket. Everything will be a string. Essentially what I want to do is store each string into a variable in a hash so i can print it into a 3 column csv file.

Here's a sample of what the file looks like:

> Student-[K-6] Exceptional in Math 
>   /home/area/kinder/mathadvance.txt, 12 
>   Students in grade K-12 shown to be exceptional in math. 
>   Placed into special after school program. 
>   See /home/area/overall/performance.txt, 200
>   
>   
>   Student-[Junior] Weak Performance 
>   Students with overall weak performance. 
>  
>   Summer program services offered as shown in 
>   "/home/area/services/summer.txt", 212 
>   Student-[K-6] Physical Excerise Time Slots
>   
>  /home/area/pe/schedule.txt, 303
>   Assigned time slots for PE based on student's grade level. Make reference to 
>   /home/area/overall/classtimes.txt, 90

I want to to have a final csv file that looks like:

> Grade,Topic,Path
>   
> K-6, Exceptional in Math, /home/area/kinder/mathadvance.txt, 12
>   
> K-6, Physical Exercise Time Slots, /home/area/pe/schedule.txt, 303
>   
> Junior, Weak Performance, "/home/area/services/summer.txt", 212

Since it's a csv file, I know it will also separate at the line number when exporting into excel but I'm fine with that.
I started off by putting the grade type into an array because I want to be able to add more strings to it for different grade levels.

My program looks like this so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @grades = ("K-6", "Junior", "Community-College", "PreK");
```

I was thinking that I will need to do some sort of system sed command to grab what is in the brackets and store it into a variable. Then I will grab everything to the right of the bracket on the line and store it into a variable. And then I will grep for a line containing "area" to get the path and I will store it as a string into a variable, put these in a hash, and then print into csv. I'm not sure if I'm thinking about this the right way. Also, I have NO IDEA how to do this for each BLOCK of text in the file. I need it by block because each block has its own corresponding grades, topics, and paths.

Comment: You want to use [Perl Regexes](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).  Your question is a good one; apologies I don't have time right now to hack out a working example for you.  The link I cited should point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
perl -000 -ne '($grade, $topic) = /\[(.*)\] (.*)/;
               ($path) = m{(.*/area/.*)};
               print "$grade, $topic, $path\n"' -- file.txt
```

- `-000` turns on paragraph mode, `-n` won't read line by line, but paragraph by paragraph
- `/\[(.*)\] (.*)/` matches the square brackets and whatever follows them up to a newline. The inside of the square brackets and the following text are captured using the parentheses.
- `m{(.*/area/.*)}` captures the line containing "area". It uses the `m{}` syntax instead of `//` so we don't have to backslash the slashes (avoiding so called "leaning toothpick syndrome")